# $modelValue is undefined while trying to access it in a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to implement an inch to mm converter... All I want is, if user enters a value in inches in text box, the text box(view) should display value in inch. Where as the model should hold the value in mm. For that I have written a directive as shown below.

The model gets updated in mm as I have checked by debugging.
But, when I click outside the text box (blur event), switch the view to some other tab in my web app and come back, the  model value is getting populated in text box again. So I thought that on focus event, I can pass $modelValue/25 (mm to inch conversion) as a parameter to $setViewValue() function. But I get $modelValue attribute as undefined.

```
.directive('metricImperialInput', function($timeout){
              return{
                  require: 'ngModel',
                  link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl){
                      element.bind("focus", function(e) {
                      $timeout(function() {
                          modelCtrl.$setViewValue(modelCtrl.$modelValue/25);
                          modelCtrl.$render();
                     }, 0);
                   });
                      modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(inputValue){
                          var changedOutput = parseInt(inputValue) * 25;
                          modelCtrl.$setViewValue(parseInt(inputValue));
                          modelCtrl.$render();
                          return parseInt(changedOutput);
                      });
                  }
              };
          });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correctly using the `ngModelController.$parsers`, but inside the parser you're also using `$setViewValue()` which is totally unneeded because the inputValue that the parser function recieves is already the `$viewValue`! So that can be removed, together with the `$render()`. The focus event is also unneeded, because it just doesn't do anything useful if you correctly use the $parsers.

So now you'll have just this remaining:

```
.directive('metricImperialInput', function($timeout){
          return{
              require: 'ngModel',
              link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl){
                modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(inputValue){
                  var changedOutput = parseInt(inputValue) * 25;
                  return parseInt(changedOutput) || 0;
                });
              }
          };
      });
```

But there is problem with this, the initial $modelValue doesn't get converted until you start using the input. For this I added the following lines to make sure that when the directive loads it will correctly set the initial values and after that the parsers handle everything.

```
var initVal = $parse(attrs.ngModel)(scope);
modelCtrl.$viewValue = initVal / 25;
modelCtrl.$modelValue = initVal;
modelCtrl.$render();
```

You can find the entire solution in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2yt04ztr/19/).

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to access the model value on input focus. Instead try to access the model value on keyup. And also use modelCtrl.$viewValue instead of modelCtrl.$modelValue. The working example is below :

```
    `element.bind("keyup", function(e) {
            $timeout(function() {
                    modelCtrl.$setViewValue(modelCtrl.$viewValue/25);
                    modelCtrl.$render();
             }, 0);
    });`
```